# Videojs: how to add a current frame display instead of time?

Tags: javascript, video.js

I want to add a new part in the control bar, which can show the current frame number of the video. I have already the FPS calculated by Flask, and I think multiplying fps and current time will do?

(Once occasionally I found there is a 'getCurrentFrame()' method showing as a prompt,but when I tried to see the initial code in file video.js, it doesn't ever exist,have you ever seen this situation?)

```
videojs("my-video").ready(function () {
       this.on('timeupdate',function () {
            window.currentframe =  Math.round(player.currentTime()*{{ fps }});
            console.log(currentframe);
       });
});
```

This snippet can show the value in the console but I don't know how to show it in the control bar.

I'm lately new to videojs ,I really wonder how can i display the current frame in the control bar, thanks!

Comment: This 'idea' seems to be not very well thought out.  There will be 24 frames every SECOND...when video is playing, the value shown will change so rapidly that it will be just a blur.  Also, your Javascript doesn't parse...the token "window.currentframe" is invalid.  It should be "var currentframe" and "fps" isn't defined.

Comment: I calculated the fps value by using 'cv2' in python,so this value is the video's proper attribute. Besides I'm also using another plugin: [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-framebyframe), so when I click the buttons ('+1','-1'), the frame number changes correctly . I don't know about yours,but here I think 'window.currentframe' and 'var currentframe' do the same.